# UIProgressView custom maximum value

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiprogressview

I'm making an app where I retrive some value from a server, the server load. This value can be from 0.00 to 100.00, but UIProgressView only allows from 0.00 to 1.00. Is there any way I can extend the 1.00 limit to 100.00?

Comment: Why don't you just divide your value by 100?

Comment: Thanks! I did this: `float sum = ([[words objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] / 1.0);` Add your comment as answer so I can accept it as correct

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suggest you simply divide your value by 100 and put it into your progressview that way.